# Improving UDP sockets throughput (upload) in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, udp

I'm developing a user-space script in C that sets up UDP sockets and tries to send packets (upload) as fast as possible, to test the maximum throughput available of the bandwidth.

Right now, with the code below, I'm achieving 65% of the maximum available bandwidth. I would like to achieve 80% or 85%.

I would like to get some suggestions or ideas on how I can improve the code below to achieve greater efficiency of CPU or Memory to achieve those 15% more of throughput.

```c
/**
 * @brief UDP client process that sends packets for a given test duration.
 * @param test_params The test parameters received.
*/
void    *udp_client_thread(void *test_params)
{
    ThreadParams    *params = (ThreadParams*)test_params;

    int             client_socket;
    char            buffer[params->mtu];
    int             packets_to_send;
    struct          sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct          timespec delta_time, current_time;
    
    /* set the entire space of the buffer with some value. */
    memset(buffer, 'a', params->mtu);

    /* Get environment values, if any */
    if (getenv("packets_batch") != NULL)
        packets_to_send = atoi(getenv("packets_batch"));
    else
        packets_to_send = 5;

    struct          iovec iov[packets_to_send];

    // Setup iovec
    for (int i = 0; i < packets_to_send; ++i)
    {
        iov[i].iov_base = buffer;
        iov[i].iov_len = params->mtu;
    }

    /* Create UDP socket */
    if ((client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        log_error("Error creating socket on user space");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*****************************/
    /* Configure Server Address */
    /***************************/
    //initialize the struct with zeros before setting specific values.
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = params->server_address.sin_port;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = params->server_address.sin_addr.s_addr;

    /******************************/
    /* Set socket's buffer size  */
    /****************************/
    // Set the buffer size of the socket (send buffer) to the system max value for a socket.
    int buffer_size;
    if (getenv("buffer_divider") != NULL)
        buffer_size = params->sys_buff_max_val / atoi(getenv("buffer_divider"));
    else
        buffer_size = params->sys_buff_max_val;

    if (setsockopt(client_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &buffer_size, sizeof(buffer_size)) == -1)
    {
        log_error("Error setting send buffer size");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Set socket to non-blocking mode */
    if (fcntl(client_socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0) 
    {
        log_error("Error setting socket to non-blocking mode");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Connect the UDP socket to the server, we no longer need to use "sendto"
    if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1)
    {
        log_error("Error connecting UDP socket");
        close(client_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /****************************/
    /* Send data to the target */
    /**************************/
    get_time(&delta_time);
    get_time(&current_time);
    delta_time.tv_sec += (params->test_timeout / 1000);
    while (time_compare(&current_time, &delta_time) != -1)
    {
        /*if (writev(client_socket, iov, packets_to_send) < 0)
        {
            log_error("Error in writev: %s", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }*/
        if (writev(client_socket, iov, packets_to_send) < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                //usleep(sleeping_time); // sleep for 10ms, then try again, resource might be available
                continue;
            } else
            {
                // Some other error occurred
                log_error("Error in writev: %s", strerror(errno));
                break;
            }
        }
        get_time(&current_time);
    }
    // Close the socket.
    close(client_socket);
    return (NULL);
}

/**
 * @brief Creates UDP socket clients and sends packets for a given test duration using multiprocessing.
 * @param test_parameters The test parameters received.
 * @param result The test result to be filled.
*/
int udp_user_space_test(Stb_ul_params *test_parameters, test_result_t *result, int monitor_cpu)
{

    int             system_max_value;
    FILE            *proc_fd;
    ThreadParams    *params;

    /*******************/
    /* set parameters */
    /*****************/
    params = malloc(sizeof(ThreadParams));
    if (params != NULL)
        memset(params, 0, sizeof(ThreadParams));
    else
    {
        log_error("Error allocating memory for thread parameters");
        return (-1);
    }
    params->mtu = get_mtu(INTERFACE_UPSTREAM);
    params->server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    params->server_address.sin_port = test_parameters->dst_port;
    params->server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = test_parameters->dst_addr;
    params->test_timeout = test_parameters->test_timeout;

    /*********************************/
    /* socket buffer system max val */
    /*******************************/
    proc_fd = fopen("/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max", "r");
    if (proc_fd == NULL)
        return (-1);
    fscanf(proc_fd, "%d", &system_max_value);
    fclose(proc_fd);
    params->sys_buff_max_val = system_max_value;

    /*********************/
    /* Create processes */
    /*******************/
    short num_of_threads;
    if (getenv("num_threads") != NULL)
        num_of_threads = (short)atoi(getenv("num_threads"));
    else
        num_of_threads = NUM_THREADS;

    /*******************/
    /* Create threads */
    /*****************/ 
    //pthread_mutex_init(&params->params_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[num_of_threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; ++i)
    {
        log_info("Creating thread %d", i);
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, udp_client_thread, (void *)params) != 0)
        {
            log_error("Error creating thread %d", i);
            return (-1);
        }
    }

    /*****************/
    /* Join threads */
    /***************/ 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; ++i)
    {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread %d\n", i);
            return (-1);
        }
    }

    /***********/
    /* FINISH */
    /*********/
    result->error_code = 300;
    test_parameters->test_status = false;
    log_info("Finished user space test");

    /* Free resources */
    free(params);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your use of threads seem strange. What good do they do here, exactly? Other than creating lots of overhead?

Comment: It seems to be more efficient to send the packets concurrently to optimize the CPU performance.

Comment: Why? I fail to see a case for parallelism in this specific example. I could be wrong of course, but have you tried without threads?

Comment: Yes, If I have a single process with a single socket, the number of packets sent is much much lower. I could try opening up multiple sockets on the same process , though.. haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Get rid of non-blocking mode. You're just pointlessly spinning, smoking the CPU, while EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK occurs. The correct technique would be to use `select()/poll()/epoll()` to tell you when the socket becomes writable again, but it is much simpler to just use  blocking mode and let the system do the work for you. And what size send buffer are you using?

Comment: I just have about 7 seconds to send the packets as fast as possible. The socket buffer is set to the system maximum value and the packet size is about the same size as the mtu configured on the NIC.

Comment: Non-blocking mode doesn't make it any faster. If anything the way you're using it makes it *slower*, as you're spinning the CPU to no effect and taking it away from other tasks, such as, err, putting datagrams onto the wire.

Comment: But multi-plexing (epoll) didn't give me better results.

Comment: I didn't exactly say that it would, did I? Only that it's the correct way to do this, and doesn't smoke the CPU. Blocking mode is an equally correct and far simpler solution.

Comment: Okay, I understand but I'am trying to prioritize whatever gives me the highest value possible in throughput.

Comment: Throughput is determined by how fast the NIC can get IP packets onto the wire. This is a lot slower than your code. And if you send too fast for the receiver you are going to get packet loss anyway. You should really be looking at the receive code.

Comment: And how can I improve the NIC getting IP packets into the wire ? Increase the size of the queu ? Increase socket buffer size ? This is what Iam trying to look into.